# MudBlazor Autocomplete not updating list with new search value

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, mudblazor

I have set up a MudBlazor Autocomplete element which gets its details from an api and return a list of movies from TMDB(The Movie Database) Api.
It then takes a Title or Name from the results and adds it to a List.

The problem i have if i type out two letters of the movie, say 'fi' for Fight Club. It searches close matches, which is fine. But if i type any more, say the entire string 'fight club', it still holds the old data.

This is what i have so far

RAZOR:

```
<MudPaper>
    <MudAutocomplete T="string" Label="Search" @bind-Value="SearchValue" SearchFunc="@Search" ResetValueOnEmptyText="true"/>
</MudPaper>

@code {
    private string SearchValue = string.Empty;
    private List<string> MovieList = new();

    private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Search(string value)
    {
        var movies = await _msService.GetMultiSearch(value); //api call
        if(movies is not null && movies.Results is not null)
        {
            foreach(var movie in movies.Results) //movies.Results is the Enumerable
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movie.Name))
                {
                    MovieList.Add(movie.Name);
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movie.Title))
                {
                    MovieList.Add(movie.Title);        
                }
            }
            return MovieList;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong

Comment: Please can you put more details of your api call ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about your solution otherwise, but with a bit of MudBlazor knowledge, it would seem you are adding the items to the same list across multiple calls to Search (meaning, appending the results from "f", "fi", "fig" etc. to the suggestion list). I suggest you do:

```cs
private List<string> MovieList = new();

private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Search(string value)
{
    var movies = await _msService.GetMultiSearch(value); //api call
    if(movies is not null && movies.Results is not null)
    {
        MovieList.Clear();
        foreach(var movie in movies.Results) //movies.Results is the Enumerable
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movie.Name))
            {
                MovieList.Add(movie.Name);
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movie.Title))
            {
                MovieList.Add(movie.Title);        
            }
        }
        return MovieList;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Either that or entirely remove MovieList from the component scope and just construct the suggestion list for each search:

```cs
private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Search(string value)
{
    var movies = await _msService.GetMultiSearch(value); //api call
    if(movies is not null && movies.Results is not null)
    {
        var movielist = new List<string>();
        foreach(var movie in movies.Results) //movies.Results is the Enumerable
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movie.Name))
            {
                movielist.Add(movie.Name);
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movie.Title))
            {
                movielist.Add(movie.Title);        
            }
        }
        return movielist;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This will prevent results from carrying over between changes in the input field.